# Safe to use # ! $ in variables in regex?

Tags: regex, linux, perl

Can someone tell me, if it is safe to have all these special characters in `@rx`? It is `#` `!` and `$` I am concerned about.

If it is not safe, how do I make sure the regex won't interpret the elements in `@rx`?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $doc = do { local $/; <STDIN> };

my @rx = (
    'mariadb:\n  build: ',
    '#!/bin/bash\n\n/usr/bin/mysqld_safe',
    'FROM centos:7',
    '#!/bin/sh\n# This is /usr/libexec/mariadb-',
    '#!/bin/bash\nVOLUME_HOME="/var/lib/mysql"',
    '#!/bin/bash\nMYSQL="/usr/bin/mysql -u$DB_ENV_DBUSER'
);

my @a = ();

foreach my $r (@rx) {
    push @a, $doc =~ /($r.{3000})/sg;
}

my $n = int(rand(999999999999999));
for my $i (0 ..$#a) {
    system("echo '$a[$i]' > ext$n$i");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can auto-escape any necessary characters by doing:

```
push @a, $doc =~ /(\Q$r\E.{3000})/sg;
```

But your regex may not be working as you intend; it will only find your strings in the first part of the file, not if they extend into the last 3000 characters.  It also will only find one of two occurrences if they don't have 3000 other characters between them.  Both problems would be fixed by doing:

```
push @a, $doc =~ /(?=(\Q$r\E.{0,3000}))/sg;
```

Comment: Very nice! What does `?=` mean?

Comment: it's a positive look ahead; it means match the stuff up through the ) but don't consume any of the string (so the next /g iteration will start looking earlier in the string)